# How to get IPv6 for libvirt/kvm guests on laptop via both wired and wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, routing, ipv6, nat, linux-kvm

How can I get KVM/libvirt guests to have transparent, global IPv6 access on a laptop that switches interfaces between wired and wireless?

I have a /56 from my ISP, my unifi gateway gets that allocation via dhcpv6-pd, and on the local network everything gets SLAAC addresses just fine.  I'm a happy ipv6 user and pass all the various tests.

But, my laptop is a PITA.  I run a "work" VM that I ... work from.  Increasingly I need this to accesses ipv6 things, including various clouds that are ipv6 only.

KVM usermode networking and NAT "just works" for ipv4.  Networkmanager manages the interfaces and makes sure the packets get out when the links come and go.  End-to-end global routing is great and all but I don't need it and this works just fine for what I'm doing in ipv4 land.

I can add the laptop wired connection to a bridge with the KVM host interface and that works fine ... But you can't add a wireless interface to a bridge.  As soon as I eject and go to wireless it all breaks.

virt-manager doesn't give any options for this.  You can enable IPv6 for a network there, but it just enables inter-vm communication (e.g.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-virtual_networking-creating_a_virtual_network)

Virtualbox somehow allows a guest to get and IPv6 address on the wifi bridged, but it doesn't work (no packets make it out or in).  Apparently, some nics it works with but others not (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5503).

Everyone says IPv6 Nat is terrible, but then there's things like https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7157 which goes into great detail about multi-homed IPv6, which this seems to be a subset of, to ultimately be 20 pages of why that doesn't work.

There's plenty of details out there for ways to setup bridges, etc (https://www.berrange.com/posts/2011/06/16/providing-ipv6-connectivity-to-virtual-guests-with-libvirt-and-kvm/) but I can't find anyone who seems to alternate IPv6 from both a wired and wireless connection to their guests?

I've become increasingly sure that it's 2020 and this just isn't possible ... But I would love to be shown that I'm wrong!

Comment: Is your /56 prefix reasonably static?

Comment: Yes for this ISP the /56 is static so they say ... though I've heard a rumour that keeping it static might soon be a value-added feature that costs a little bit more (just because they can I guess).  So I would prefer to not hardcode routes, if I can. Ultimately I'd like to take my laptop anywhere, including other ipv6 networks and have it "just work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPv6 NAT is the easiest way to make this "just work".  A simple sample setup is described at

https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#examplesNATv6

Note, as at September 2020 you will need a very recent version of libvirt (git master or 6.8.0 when it is released).  You will need [927acaedec7effbe67a154d8bfa0e67f7d08e6c7](https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/commit/927acaedec7effbe67a154d8bfa0e67f7d08e6c7) and [d9ee51ef46b922db353ccb6cb6f559a559a6d186](https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/commit/d9ee51ef46b922db353ccb6cb6f559a559a6d186).